# Why does my car cut off the first time I try to start it?

Tags: engine, nissan, skyline

I'm trying to figure the problem with my 2004 Nissan Skyline I purchased about a year ago. Every time I start my car it cuts right off and for it to stay on I have to press the gas pedal in order to keep the RPM up to 1,000. I had it on the computer recently and everything seems to be in order, it didn't say if my sensor had gone which is a good thing.

It will start early in the morning and if I do not drive often it will start. For example, I leave home at 8 am and it will start. I then arrive at work at 8:30 am and when I leave work at around 10 am it will not start unless I press the gas pedal to keep the RPM up to 1,000. Another instance, I leave home at 8 am to go to work and it will start. Then I leave work at around 8 pm and it will start. My observation is that it will start according to the temperature whether its cool or warm and not hot.

Can you give me a few ideas as to what it is causing this problem?

Comment: Glad you got your question in.  Hope you get a good answer.  Welcome to the stie.  Cheers!

Comment: You state in your question, " I purchase from you all about a year ago"  Stack Exchange does not sell cars.  Was that intentional or a mistake?

Comment: I had a rough idle in my '06 Infinti G35 (US version of the V35 Skyline) that was caused by a clogged injector. I ran a bottle of Sea Foam gas additive and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Most common cause is the ECM Coolant temp sensor may be bad or out of range, replace it. If you have a scanner that can display live data this would help diagnose this as you can see the coolant temp the ecm is receiving from the sensor. Read the temp live data when it has starting issues. The temp when cold should be very close to outside air temperature.